# How to verify that the code in this open source tool doesn't misuse your Google Account credentials?

Tags: javascript, jquery, security, google-chrome, screen-scraping

[image: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/mbigbapnjcgaffohmbkdlecaccepngjd]

This [Chrome scraping tool](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/mbigbapnjcgaffohmbkdlecaccepngjd) has open sourced its code here:

https://github.com/mnmldave/scraper

How would one verify that the code in this tool doesn't misuse your Google Account credentials when it uploads the scraped data to Google Spreadsheets?

Comment: Do you give the tool your Google credentials, or is it using those entered in Chrome? If the latter, chances are the extension never gets to see them in clear text. (I'm no expert in this though so I don't know for sure how this works)

Comment: @Pekka: I think it just uses whatever is set in Chrome. I don't think it ever asks for them explicitly. Don't really understand the code but I got worried when it said it has access to "1. Your data on all websites and 2. Your browsing history".

Comment: Those permissions are as broad as possible. `1` means it can add some sort of code to every page you visit, this is often done by extensions that have keyboard shortcuts or extensions that want to prevent some kind of code to run on every page.

Answer (score 2):

Code uses [oAuth](http://oauth.net/) for authentication, so software won't store your user/pass itself.

It will require permissions to various Google services that are linked to your account.

For example if it requests Google Contacts permission and you don't want to share your contact list with the program, then don't grant an access.